# flutter devices command does not recognise android device

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I installed flutter for vscode and all the other dependencies without using Android Studio. I have a Xiaomi POCO F1 and I wanted to use it for debugging and running the app.

I switched to developer mode on my android device and enabled USB debugging, connected my device to the laptop via a USB cable downloaded the usb driver for the device and ran the `flutter devices` command but it shows that only chrome is connected.

I tried to update the driver for the device from the device manager but it does not get installed. Instead there is a MTP Device Driver pre installed and it doesn't allow any other driver to get installed.

I tried a lot of articles from Google and StackOverflow but none seems to work.
Could anyone please help me figure out what I'm missing out or doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For more clarity on your issue result of command flutter doctor is required.

```
  flutter doctor
```

Comment: I did but it does not show the connected android device